# HttpClient adds half-second for each request. Why?

Tags: c#, http, dotnet-httpclient

I want to download something from web using HttpClient.
I've noticed, that time of request tracked by Fiddler and by Stopwatch in C# differs significantly. Here, take a look:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void HttpClientSpeedTest()
    {
        TestHttmlClient().Wait();
        Assert.IsFalse(false);
    }

    private async Task TestHttmlClient() {
        var url = "http://www.rbc.ru";
        var timer = new Stopwatch();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            timer.Start();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            timer.Stop();
            Debug.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed);
            timer.Start();
            string jsonstr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            timer.Stop();
            Debug.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed);
        }
    }
```

Gives me: **00:00:00.4277788** for first measurement - getting the response, **00:00:00.4360716** for second measurement - ReadAsStringAsync (that's accumulated, so about 0.43 seconds for the whole request).

BUT! If we look at the **same request in Fiddler**, I get:

```
ClientConnected:    13:59:34.334
ClientBeginRequest: 13:59:34.364
GotRequestHeaders:  13:59:34.364
ClientDoneRequest:  13:59:34.364
Determine Gateway:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         0ms
TCP/IP Connect:     3ms
HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
ServerConnected:    13:59:34.367
FiddlerBeginRequest:13:59:34.367
ServerGotRequest:   13:59:34.367
ServerBeginResponse:13:59:34.383
GotResponseHeaders: 13:59:34.383
ServerDoneResponse: 13:59:34.440
ClientBeginResponse:13:59:34.440
ClientDoneResponse: 13:59:34.440

**Overall Elapsed:  0:00:00.076**
```

The question is why HTTPClient added half-a-second? and how to avoid it?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you avoid the `await` keyword? (ie. `var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result`)

Comment: Not much. 00:00:00.5277214 in C# vs 0:00:00.178 in Fiddler